# relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object

Tags: c, static-libraries, static-linking, linkage, relocation

I am compiling a static library, which leverages some inline assembly code.

I notice that when I use labels for the `jmp` instruction:

```
int foo(){

 asm volatile
 (
    "mov    0x60(%r8),%r11d\n\t"
    "jmp    *S_401a70\n\t"
    ...
    "S_401a70: xor %rax, %rax\n\t"
    ...
 )
}
```

and compile the code into a static library with the following flags:

```
-Wl,--no-undefined -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles -L$(SOME_LIBRARY_PATH) \
-Wl,--whole-archive -l$(SOME_Library_Name) -Wl,--no-whole-archive \
-Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--no-undefined \
-Wl,-pie,-eenclave_entry -Wl,--export-dynamic  \
-Wl,--defsym,__ImageBase=0
```

I would get some errors like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Enclave/libtest.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

However, since I am compiling into a static library, I don't think `-fPIC` would make sense. I tried so, but it doesn't work at all.

This seems like an issue with the `gcc assembly extension`, but I am not sure. Could anyone shed some lights on this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried removing the indirect (`*`) from the `jmp` instruction? That should make a relative jump instead, which looks like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a tool issue. First of all `-fPIC` affects only C code. And affects it in such way that generated code won't contain absolute addresses of referred data/code and won't rely on its own address in memory (it is a somewhat simplified explanation). Next - it has nothing to do with assembly inlines. Since here code was generated by programmer. And if it is written in a way that introduces absolute addresses or some stuff that introduces dependency on its memory location - compiler can't help with it.

P.S. You may built static library even with position-dependent code but it won't be accepted by linker if someone will try to link it into shared library, since resulting shared library should be position-independent.

Comment: Well mostly I think it is due to the `label`. The reason is that when I comment out `"jmp    *S_401a70\n\t"`, the building process becomes correct.